# Multivariable Calculus- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ implies... ?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was wondering... given a function $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ , is it true that when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =0 $  , then $f$ does not depend on $x$ at all ?

Is it true for every function, in every region we take ?

Thanks experts!

Comment: If the derivative vanishes everywhere, your claim is true

Comment: But if this is only true in a specific set. Is the statement true in this set?

Comment: This claim is not true point-wise for example $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=x^2$ vanishes at $x=0$. It is true in open sets

Answer (score 0):

Your first claim is true as was pointed out in a comment. However, if we change the domain, this is not totally true: let
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x<0 \, \mathrm{or}\, x\geq 0 \, \mathrm{and}\, y\neq 0\}
$$
This is just $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the semi-ray  of positives numbers on the $x$-axis and without the origin.
Let
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x & \mathrm{if}\,  y<0 \, \mathrm{and} \, x\geq 0\\
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the value of $f$ depends on the two coordinates, however, we have that for every $(x,y)\in A$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ exists and is equal to zero.